# how to sort an object alphabetically within an array, in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an app using React.js and firebase where users can enter the name, and the person's address.

The object in firebase looks like this:

`L1NSTjqA10Qc85d7Kcc
 - name: John Doe,
 - address: 1 Maple Ave`

I have printed the name, and address successfully onto the DOM, but i would like to sort it alphabetically, by the name.

So my list would look like this for example:

```
Jane Doe - 34 Green Street
John Doe - 1 Maple Ave
Riley Smith - 3 Happy Street
```

Here is my JSX so far, for when mapping over the array of objects, on the parent component:

```
<ul>
  {this.state.contacts.map((res)=> <List data={res}/>)}
</ul>
```

and just in case, here is my componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const dbRef = firebase.database().ref();

  dbRef.on("value", (firebaseData) => {
    const itemsArray = [];
    const itemsData = firebaseData.val();
    for (let itemKey in itemsData) {
      itemsArray.push(itemsData[itemKey])
    }
    this.setState({ contacts: itemsArray})
  })
}
```

I have tried to do the following, from another stack overflow forum, however it did not work:

```
const myData = [].concat(this.state.contacts)
  .sort((a,b)=> a.name > b.name
  .map((res)=> <List data={res}/>);
```

Answer (score 35):

The logic part where you are trying to sort and then map can be done like this.

```
const myData = this.state.contacts
 .sort(function(a, b) {
  if(a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase()) return -1;
  if(a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase()) return 1;
  return 0;
 })
 .map((item, i) => <List key={i} data={item} />);
```

Or if you want to do it even shorter you can do it like this.

```
const myData = this.state.contacts
 .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
 .map((item, i) => <List key={i} data={item} />);
```

[`localeCompare` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) is a method of `String`

In your method called

```
dbRef.on("value", (firebaseData) => {
  this.setState({ 
      contacts: Array.from(firebaseData.val()).sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))})
  });
}
```

In your `render` method do the following

```
 render () {
    return (
      <ul>
       {
        this.state.contacts.map((item, i) => <List key={i} data={item} />)
       }
      </ul>
    );
 }
```

Does this help?

Comment: How can i add this into my JSX? I have tried to enter in your shortened answer inside the "return", however, it gives me errors. Should I add this in after the render method but before the return? Please advise, thank you

Comment: nevermind, I have figured it out: i placed it in the render method, before the return, but called the variable in the jsx. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Anyways I did update my answer. If this answer helped you kindly consider marking as your answer. and giving it a thumbs up. Cheers.

Comment: @AdeelImran you don't need to do this: `itemsArray = itemsArray.sort` as `.sort` is changing the array [in place](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Return_value). and you shouldn't do this: `this.state.contacts.sort` as you are mutating the state. this is the reason the OP used the `[].concat`, to create a new array.

Comment: Understood, I updated that part of the code as well. I still feel `[].concat` is an old school method. So i simply used `Array.from` and sorted the result.

Comment: `localeCompare` helped me, thanks. Small question, does **locale** in `localeCompare` affected by app translation or something like that?

Comment: @tuan maybe this will help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Answer (score 4):

Do **not** sort the data inside your render method! it will sort it on each render call.

Another thing to remember is that [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is doing a [manipulation on the array and not returning a new copy of the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Return_value).
From the docs:

> Note that the array is sorted in place, and no copy is made

This means you will mutate the `state` object, which is a big No No in react.
This is why you are using `[].concat(this.state.contacts)`, to create a new array. 
You can achieve a new array with the [ES2015 spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
const newArray = [...this.state.contacts];
```

Anyway, Instead of dealing with copies and mutation of the state, do the sorting just before you are storing the array in your state:

```
itemsArray.sort((a,b) => {
    return a.name > b.name;
});
this.setState({
    contacts: itemsArray
})
```

Comment: it won't perform a rerender on the `sort` part unless the the state is updated again. That is only when you render method is updated.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what i wrote? "_it will do it on each render call_". by the way the `render` method is not updating (it's a function it will get invoked). the state which is an object will be updated.

Comment: What I inferred from your statement was that you are saying that every time the array gets sorted a re-render will happen. You do it inside the render() method or outside. Every time you update your state your render method will be called again. And to be very precise I don't think the op is calling `setState` method in her render method. So why would that be an issue?

Comment: This is simple, you have a function `render` inside that function you are doing some sorting. each time `render` gets called you will do this sorting again (probably for no good reason). the `render`  method will get called on **every** update of the state, so the OP may have other data in the state that can get updated and this will trigger a `render` call which will sort the array again. like i mentioned, for no good reason.

Comment: I see what you mean. Apologize. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @AdeelImran +1 don't forget that `.sort` is mutating the array. so if you do it inside the `render` directly on the `state` object, you will mutate the `state`.

Comment: Yes I understand it, Array is by reference is javascript. So I will end up mutating state which is not what I want. understood. Thank you. Everyday I learn or revise something. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Very Easy Solution for apply sorting on multiple columns with only 2 functions.

Does not require toLowerCase , simply convert into string using ""

Simply create that both function

```
compareBy(key) {
return function (a, b) {
  if (""+a[key]<(""+b[key])) return -1;
  if (""+a[key]>(""+b[key])) return 1;
  return 0;
};}

sortBy(key) {
let arrayCopy = [...this.state.data];
arrayCopy.sort(this.compareBy(key));
//arrayCopy.reverse(); for descending
this.setState({data: arrayCopy});
} 

//write this in th
onClick={() => this.sortBy('column name')}
```

it is ascending sort if you want descending use 
arrayCopy.reverse()

it sort according to ASCII format so use toLowerCase for String

Answer (score 0):

.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.sort) - parseFloat(b.sort))

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).